# Colorize the source code?

Tags: color, sourcecode

Is there a way to colorize the source code, e.g. if i have

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\section*{First}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
\begin{compactenum} [\color{black!100}$\bullet$]
\item just
\item some
\item random
\item text
\end{compactenum}
\end{document}
```

Can I highlight some parts of the source code so that the coloring is visible IN THE SOURCE CODE?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Source code highlighting as through an editor or highlighting a LaTeX source code in a document?

Comment: Do you mean having some tokens of your text appear colored in your TeX-file editor ? As in, passing some coloring instructions to your syntax highlighter ? That would depend on said text editor. Otherwise, TeX files are [plain text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_text).

Comment: Any decent editor should support syntax highlighting, usually customisable.  If you want to just display your source code coloured, of course you can: `\documentclass{standalone}%
\usepackage{xcolor,listings}%
\lstset{language=TeX,keywordstyle=\color{blue}}%
\begin{document}%
\lstinputlisting{\jobname.tex}%
\end{document}%` (all lines end with % so you can see the line breaks)

Comment: @marsupilam Yes this is what I want to do. I'm using TeXStudio..

Comment: @GuestUser Then please be specific what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Texstudio already provides syntax highlighting by default. If you have switched it of just reactivate it in the menu `View` → `Highlighting`. In the example below I'm using syntax highlighting for language `(La)TeX`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you want to achieve, but there are several options to get source code highlighted, such as using the right editor (e.g. editors like Texworks, Texmaker etc.). That won't highlight your source code in the resulting file, but while editing.

If you want to use source code in your document as so-called "listing" you should have a look at the packages `listings` and `minted`. That won't highlight your source code while editing, but in the resulting output file.

Of course it is also possible to combine both options.